# How can I blacklist a program from accessing a mic or volume controls?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, voip

In this particular case, I have a program that ignores settings for mic usage (eg, it always-transmits even when its own push-to-talk and such is set, and causes all other program's volume to be attenuated because windows sees it as a valid VOIP program).

I want this program to have no input from my microphone, and preferably to also have it be ignored for volume attenuation, so that I can use a different VOIP program instead while it's running.

Is this possible to do in Windows 7? Are there any third-party programs that may be able to do this?